# storing objects with raven db exception on SaveChanges for key generation

Tags: c#, ravendb

I get the following error when storing my object(s) in RavenDb
I am only assigning one key to the stored object, I am using the overloaded store method to store the entity.
Store is only called *once* so why would an exception like this be thrown. There is something about object identity I don't understand.

The `Id` property has another purpose besides ravendb persistence.

`Entity UserQuery+MyItem had document key 'mykeypath/44' but now has document key property 'MyItems/44'. You cannot change the document key property of a entity loaded into the session`.

#### Edited to include complete source code

```
void Main()
{
    var host = "http://myhost:8020";

    var _documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = host, DefaultDatabase = "sdb" };
    _documentStore.Initialize();
    using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession()) 
    {
        var path = "mykeypath/44";
        session.Store(new MyItem { Id = 303, Test = "TEST" }, path);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class MyItem : AuditableEntity {
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class AuditableEntity : IAuditable
{
   [DataMember]
   [Display(Name = "Id", Description = "Id")]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   [Display(Name = "Modified By", Description = "Modified By")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   [Display(Name = "Modified Date", Description = "Modified Date")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you actually posted the exception

Comment: The exception is "Entity MyItem had document key 'contract/10' but now has document key 'myitems/10'. I only ever store (and assign) one key.

Comment: Please post more complete code so we can reproduce the exception.  Thanks.

Comment: I have included the full source code, that can be executed from linqpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class has a property called `Id`, RavenDB will use that as document id by default.

In your case, having an instance of `MyItem` with `Id` set to `303`, means that the document will be saved in the database with an Id of `MyItems/303`.

You can test that easily by modifying the

```
session.Store(new MyItem { Id = 303, Test = "TEST" }, path);
```

line with

```
session.Store(new MyItem { Id = 303, Test = "TEST" });
```

This will work and the result will be:

[image: Saved document]

So, the issue is that you are instructing Raven to assign two IDs to your object:

- `MyItems/303`, due to the value of the `Id` property
- `mykeypath/44`, due to the fact that you're explicitly setting this Id by using the `Store` overload.

The solution I would apply in this case is to rename the `Id` property. If that's not possible (ex: the class is already used for other purposes, like a WCF contract), consider creating a new class used solely for RavenDB persistence and map between the two (tools like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) make this easy).

#### Update

I found a way to bend the `Id` field convention by looking at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/Ly10rvbVrcM).
In your case, you should do the following prior to opening the session:

```
_documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty =
    prop =>
        {
            if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof (AuditableEntity))
                return prop.Name == "CustomId";

            return prop.Name == "Id";
        };
```

What this says is that the property `Id` defined by the type `AuditableEntity` should not be used as a document identifier. In all other cases, do the default.

I tested it and it works fine, showing two Id fields in the RavenDb studio :) :

[image]

Comment: Hi w0lf, as much as I don't like it, your answer seems correct. I was hoping for a method of instructing raven to ignore the id property, and use the value I supplied to the store method. I will think about the implications of this, and change my models accordingly. Thanks very much for finally clearing this up. I think I failed to express myself clearly in the initial question.

Comment: @Jim please see the update to my answer. I found another solution that you may find more useful.